# Older Api documentation

Tags: opengl, api

I am currently using a older IntelHd Gpu which supports **Opengl3.1 (Glsl #version140)**.

While trying to locate the relevant Api for this version ,the Khronos site only provides  [documentation for Opengl2.1 and Opengl4.5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/).

On their [Github page](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages) documentation for Opengl2.1 and Opengl4 is available.

How to locate the Api for Opengl 3.1?

Comment: While this question is totally valid to be asked here, I would suggest to ask directly in the OpenGL forums: https://community.khronos.org/ --- Alternatively, you might open an issue on their GitHub site. You will probably get a quicker answer there. In case you do, please answer your own question with the links/information you got there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older Opengl Api documentation can be found at this  [Official Khronos Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php#oldspecs)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL 4.5 reference pages have tables at the bottom of each page indicating in which version particular function was added. For example, if you look at [glTexStorage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml), you can see that it was introduced in 4.2, while its DSA equivalent in 4.5.

I think that the reason for having separate pages for 2.1 and 4.5 is that the former includes legacy functions, while the latter has only core profile functions.